# Mimic Java BufferedReader.readLine() on a URL, using cUrl and Bash

Tags: bash, curl

I'm dealing with a legacy system that requires sending "\r" to the connection to get the next line for parsing.

This is easy with Java:

```
URL url = new URL("http://some.url");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

However, my unix skills are not great, so I don't exactly know how to even google for this answer.

It's obvious that the connection is left open, and it's expecting a "\r" to be sent (which is where the BufferedReader.readLine() method comes in), but I don't know how to do that in bash (either in a script or from the prompt). Also, every search includes 99% results based in PHP. I don't have a scripting language available to me, just bash.

Comment: I don't think `curl` is the tool to use, since this sounds like a partly interactive session (get some data, send '\r', get some more data).

Comment: At the very least this focuses my research. I'm going to leave the question open for a little while, but thanks for now.

Answer (score 1):

You can read and write to arbitrary TCP ports in bash:

```
while read line; do
    ...
done < /dev/tcp/some.url/80

echo $'\r' > /dev/tcp/some.url/80
```

That gives you something to start with, anyway; I don't claim the above is a complete solution to your problem.